# opening local website from another computer in the same network

Tags: windows, ubuntu, localhost

I have a vm machine `V(1.2.3.4)` in a host `A(5.6.7.8)`, and a host `B(5.6.7.9)` in the same network as A wants to open the website in V. That is to open `http://configured_address/` from B browser.

I guess this is impossible and want to confirm.

Comment: Put your VM on a bridged network connection and then access it by IP address. That should work.

Comment: Thank you John <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is not in any way impossible.

First put your VM on a bridged network connection to enable ready access from another machine .

Then you can access it by IP address.

You can also access by computer name in a simple setup using your HOSTS file